# C# garbage collecting reasons?

Tags: c#, wpf, json.net, garbage-collection

I have the following code as a WPF app.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace TestLeak {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();

            Random RND = new Random();

            int SIZE = 100000;

            double fValue0 = 0;
            double fValue1 = 0;
            double fValue2 = 0;

            JArray aValues0 = new JArray(new double[SIZE]);
            JArray aValues1 = new JArray(new double[SIZE]);
            JArray aValues2 = new JArray(new double[SIZE]);
            JArray aValues = new JArray();
            aValues.Add(aValues0);
            aValues.Add(aValues1);
            aValues.Add(aValues2);

            DispatcherTimer oTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal);
            oTimer.Tick += new EventHandler((oSender, aArgs) => {
                for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                    fValue0 += 1;
                    fValue1 += 1;
                    fValue2 += 1;
                    aValues0[i] = fValue0;
                    aValues1[i] = fValue1;
                    aValues2[i] = fValue2;
                }
            });
            oTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            oTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why the GC needs to work *that* hard, what is it collecting? It's just basic assignment and overwriting (kind of an)array values. Could it be an issue with NewtonSoft Jarray objects?

The issue is that for my app, the interval is way smaller (aiming for ~16ms) but on each step the GC alone takes 40+ms to complete.

Thank you!

[Garbage Collection at work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFTE2.png)

Comment: "what is it collecting" -- good question, why are you asking us? Go look what your code is collecting. I would point out that creating a WPF window is very resource intensive and you might not measure what you think you're measuring, since whatever that thing you wrote is doing, it's doing it in the WPF window constructor.

Comment: @Blindy, well, not sure how the WPF window can have such an impact. Especially since the same loop but with the increments commented ( //fValue0 += 1; ) does not trigger GC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating 300k objects every tick because `JArray.operator[]` is of type `JToken`, which is a reference class. You're assigning doubles to them for every item of every one of your three arrays, which implicitly creates `JValue` instances:

```
    public static implicit operator JToken(double value)
    {
        return new JValue(value);
    }
```

That's what the garbage collector is collecting.

Comment: Note that `JValue` values are mutable, so you don't need to create new instances all the time. Simply use the `JValue.Value` property to increment their values.